# Can't install TinyTeX on Windows Server

Tags: r, tinytex

This is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/326), but the solutions mentioned didn't work for me. I tried to install TinyTeX via different methods:

- `tinytex::install_tinytex()`
- [download](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex-releases) `TinyTeX-0.zip`, and use `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()` on it
- manually extract `TinyTeX-0.zip` (`unzip()` works) and run `install-tl-windows` (Batch file)

In the first two cases, I have this error:

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In extract(pkg, exdir = path.expand(target)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

In the third case, the Windows console looks like this:

```
'\\crc\users\etienne\Desktop\TinyTeX-0\TinyTeX'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

and then closes without doing anything.

In every case, `tinytex::is_tinytex()` returns `FALSE` and `tinytex::tlmgr_path()` returns nothing.

I am working on Windows Server 2019 Standard (1809). What should I do?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0    tinytex_0.33.1 xfun_0.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/327)

In summary:

- run `tinytex::install_tinytex(dir = "<path>")` where `<path>`  is a local folder on the server, e.g in my case "C:/Users/etienne/TinyTeX"
- put `options(tinytex.tlmgr.path = tinytex:::find_tlmgr("<path>"))` in your `.Rprofile` (you can easily do that with `usethis::edit_r_profile("user")`)
- restart R
- check that `tinytex::is_tinytex()` is `TRUE` (you can also try to install a package with `tinytex::tlmgr_install("booktabs")` for instance)